# Model to DTO strategy

Tags: spring, web-services, dto, orika

I have a web project in which I present a WS api using CXF for WS, Spring for DI, Hibernate for persistence, and currently Orika for DO-DTO mapping. These are two of my entities:

```
@Entity
public class Course {

    @Id
    private Long courseId;

    @Column
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "scheduleId")
    private Schedule schedule;
    ...
}

@Entity
public class Schedule {

    @Id
    private Long scheduleId;

    @Column
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="schedule")
    private List<Course> courses;
    ...
}
```

My question is in regard to the right approach when creating the DTO objects. As you can see these to objects have a bidirectional relationship so creating 1:1 DTOs will result in circular references when CXF is about to marshal them into XML for the WebService.

This is what I've done so far:

```
@Service("scheduleService")
public class ScheduleService extends AbstractService implements IScheduleService{

@Autowired
private IScheduleDAO scheduleDAO;

public List<ScheduleDTO> getSchedules() {
        List<ScheduleDTO> schedulesDTO = new ArrayList<ScheduleDTO>();
        List<Schedule> schedules = scheduleDAO.findAll();
        for(Schedulep:schedules) {
            schedulesDTO.add(this.map(p, ScheduleDTO.class));
        }
        return schedulesDTO;
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly=true)
    public ScheduleDTO getSchedule(Long id) {
        Schedule schedule = scheduleDAO.findById(id);
        ScheduleDTO scheduleDTO = new ScheduleDTO();
        this.map(schedule, scheduleDTO);
        return scheduleDTO;
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly=true)
    public ScheduleWithCoursesDTO getScheduleWithCourses(Long id) {
        //loads schedule object and join fetchs all associated courses
        Schedule schedule = scheduleDAO.findWithCourses(id);
        ScheduleWithCoursesDTO sch =  this.map(schedule, ScheduleWithCoursesDTO.class);
        return sch;
    }
}
```

As you can see I have a `ScheduleDTO` object which only has basic attributes (no relations) and then a "special" `ScheduleWithCoursesDTO` that includes a list of `CourseDTO` class, which only contains basic attributes. This way feels awkward to me; I can think of use cases where I'll need to retrieve all the courses with a `Schedule`, and also use cases where I'll need to retrieve Courses with its associated Schedule. Is it the usual procedure to create these "special DTO" objects for every combination of relationships you may need? Is there another way I am missing? Maybe there's a way to tell Orika or any other mapper to ignore certain properties for a given mapping execution (as opposed to configuring it globally).

ScheduleDTO:

```
public class ScheduleDTO  {

    private Long scheduleId;

    private String name;

}
```

ScheduleWithCoursesDTO

```
public class ScheduleWithCoursesDTO extends ScheduleDTO {

   private List<CourseDTO> courses;
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a way and some people love to have this "contextual" mappings.
Personally I don't like this, I prefer to have a proper DTO for each use-case, I suppose that the DTO is some how a contract and/or a documentation for data involved in an operation/service.

Mapping code in Orika still a Java code and we can re-use it, organized it as we do for "business" code.
creating new DTO is not a big deal we can have as much as we need, it's not problem. You can NewScheduleDTO BasicInfoScheduleDTO FullDetailsScheduleDTO as you like.

If you really have some serious use cases that need contextual mapping / conditional
You can use Orika Filter API or manage multiple MapperFactory for each context.

Comment: how do you do those "contextual" mappings?